# How to append extra routes to current SUMO scenario?

Tags: sumo

I recently generated a Sumo scenario using `OSMWebWizard.py`. Then, using NetEdit, I added the edges to `osm.net.xml` and saved the extra 6 routes in a file calling it `extra.rou.xml` with its demands.

I would like to know how to append `extra.rou.xml` to my current scenario, so the SUMO will understand these 6 routes are also part of the scenario when running the run.bat file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the osm.sumocfg and add your extra.rou.xml to the list of route files. It will probably look like this then:

```
...
    <input>
        <net-file value="osm.net.xml"/>
        <route-files value="osm.passenger.trips.xml,extra.rou.xml"/>
        <additional-files value="osm.poly.xml"/>
    </input>
...
```